# jQuery Validation in WebForms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

In Asp.Net master page and content page scenario, how can we define all the options of jquery validation in master page as shown below...

```
$('form').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "ErrorText",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is(":radio")) {
            error.insertAfter(element.closest('ul.radio'));
        } else if (element.is(":checkbox")) {
            error.insertAfter(element.next());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        return false;  // this will override error class applying on element.
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        return false;  // this will override error class applying on element.
    }
});
```

...and then validate controls on conten pages by loading validation rules individually for that page.

I have individual scripts loaded for every content page separately and then a common script on master page with all the validation options defined above.

The problem with this approach is the single form in ASP.Net web forms.

**Code:**

Conten Page Script Example:

```
$('#controlid').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

Comment: you need to load jquery & jquery validation engine

Comment: They are loaded as pre-requisite already.

Comment: can yuo provide code on jsfiddle

Comment: jsFiddle will not help in explaining the above scenario. However, I have updated the question to elaborate.

Comment: please provide form id in place of form

Comment: It doesn't matter. id or generic 'form' selector will work. Already tested that.

Comment: is tuff to get the problem because according to me code is correct

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47305/discussion-between-nexus23-and-jain)

Answer (score 0):

I did couple of mistakes...

1) Validation options script in master page was added after the content page script was loaded, which wasn't registering the validation rules correctly to the controls.

2) Before separating the files for individual page I was using one script file which contained all the validation rules of all controls of all pages. So for every page where a control with specific id wasn't found, it was giving error "form" element cannot be found.

Probably someone can learn from my mistake!!! :)